# How to find the DistinguishedName or OU of a list of devices in CSV / Excel using Powershell / Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, distinguishedname

I have an Excel / CSV file with a list of computer names, i am trying to find the OU / DistinguishedName that each of these computers belongs to using PowerShell / Active Directory.

I am very new to this and have only gotten to about here:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -searchbase "OU=OUname, DC=DCname"
select DistinguishedName
```

This just lists all the computers in the OU, but i need to find the OU from the CSV / Excel i have

I have tried using excel / AD export but it doesnt provide desired result and search AD via powershell only finds the whole list of computers

I need to find what OU the devices on my list are in.

Either via importing the CSV or listing each device in the script.

thank you for any help!

Comment: I commend to your attention Microsoft Learn on [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.3), [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3), and [Get-ADComputer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=windowsserver2022-ps). Think about the _relationship_ between the information in your CSV, and the DN of the computer.

Comment: You might also find [Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7.3) and [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3) to be interesting and useful commands for exploring your data.